# Automorphisms of algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

The algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ can be written as the union $\bar{\mathbb{Q}} = \bigcup \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha\in\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a finite Galois field extension over $\mathbb{Q}$. An automorphism $\phi\colon \bar{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ sends every $\alpha$ to another zero of its minimal polynomial. How can we choose for every such $\alpha$ an $\tilde{\alpha}$ such that the map $\phi(q)=q$ if $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\phi(\alpha)=\tilde{\alpha}$ is a well-defined automorphism?

Edit: My question really is: suppose I have chosen the image of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, how do I show that $\phi$ is well-defined on the intersection $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$?

Comment: Consider the tower $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K/\mathbb{Q}$ where $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension (for example the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$)

Comment: just put them all in a list and choose their image one at a time.

Comment: Look at $\alpha= \sqrt[3]{2}, \beta = 1+e^{2i \pi / 3} \sqrt[3]{2}$. Then  $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\beta)=\mathbb{Q}$, but since $\alpha$ and $\beta-1$ are roots of $x^3-2$, you can't choose $\phi(\alpha)$ independently of $\phi(\beta)$. That's why you should to look at Galois extensions : If $K$ and $L$ are the normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $ \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$, what indicates that you can't choose $\phi|_K$ and $\phi|_L$ independently is that $K \cap L \ne \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot arbitrarily pick elements $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ and send them to elements $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$ such that $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ have the same minimum polynomial; what you choose for $\alpha_i$ might restrict what you can choose for $\alpha_j$.

(For instance: consider $\alpha_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $\alpha_2 = \sqrt{3}$, $\alpha_3 = \sqrt{6}$. Once you've picked either $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$ as the image of $\alpha_1$ and you've picked either $\sqrt{3}$ or $-\sqrt{3}$ for the image of $\alpha_2$, you have no freedom anymore in choosing the image of $\alpha_3$).

What you can do, is start with an algebraic extension $K$ of ${\mathbb Q}$, take an automorphism of $K$, and then extend that automorphism to $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: You do not need any form of choice.